# preg_match within braces with optional existence additional content within braces sometimes

Tags: php, regex

i have data like so

```
 $data =  '<a href="not important"><span class="theclass">data (not important)</span></a> <span class="anotherclass">extra data (October 1, 2010)</span>';
```

i want to get the date within the braces so ive done the following preg_match

```
preg_match("/\((([a-zA-Z]{5,10} .*?)|(\d{4}))\)/i",$data,$res);
```

please not that sometimes 'October 1' is not present BUT THE YEAR IS ALWAYS PRESENT hence the OR condition.... the thing is it gives me array of 3 in this case, i know its because of the set of 3 braces i have for each condition , is there any other better and cleaner way to achieve this ?

2nd condition method

```
   $data =  <a href="not important"><span class="theclass">data</span></a> <span class="theother">data <a href="not importand">data</a>  (2009)</span>
        </h3>
```

Thanks guys

Comment: **Don't use regular expressions to parse HTML.  Use a proper HTML parsing module.** You cannot reliably parse HTML with regular expressions, and you will face sorrow and frustration down the road. As soon as the HTML changes from your expectations, your code will be broken. See http://htmlparsing.com/php for examples of how to properly parse HTML with PHP modules that have already been written, tested and debugged.

Comment: even if i use say xpath dom i would still need a class ref by with it can get the data. thats pretty much the same thing ive done with preg_match , well before the below preg so i dont get why people are against it...it is that the others are more lightweight?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Use [lookarounds](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)**

Here we're making sure there is a preceding `(` character, then we look for text we would see in a date formatted like your example. This little bit of code says ALLOW for alpha numeric characters, a literal space character, and a comma, as well as digits `([A-Za-z ,\d]+)?`. The `+` character means *at least 1*. It's not as greedy as `.*` or `.+`. I'm surrounding it with parenthesis and then adding a `?` character to make it not required. It works similar to your `|` *or* statement logically because it will still find the year, but we're not making PHP do more work by parsing another check. Then we find the year (always 4 digits `{4}`). Then we check to make sure it's followed by a literal `)` character. The look behind `(?<=\()` and the look ahead `(?=\))` will find a match, but they are not included in the match results, leaving your answer clean.

Since [`preg_match()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) returns an `array()` we're catching the first element in the array. If you're looking for multiple matches in the same string you can use `preg_match_all`.

```
$data =  '<a href="not important">
   <span class="theclass">data (not important)</span></a>
   <span class="anotherclass">extra data (October 1, 2010)</span>
   <span class="anotherclass">extra data (2011)</span>';
$pattern = '!(?<=\()([A-Za-z ,\d]+)?[\d]{4}(?=\))!';
$res = preg_match_all($pattern,$data,$myDate);

print_r($myDate[0]);
```

**output**

```
Array
(
    [0] => October 1, 2010
    [1] => 2011
)
```

If you're only looking for one match you would change the code to this:

```
$res = preg_match($pattern,$data,$myDate);

echo($myDate[0]);
```

**Output**

```
October 1, 2010
```

Another way to write the pattern would be like this... we've removed the parenthesis (grouping) and the plus `+` modifier followed by the conditional `?`, but left the first set. Then we're using a `*` to make it conditional. The difference is with preg_match and preg_match_all, any groupings are also stored in the array. Since this isn't a group, then it will not store extra array elements.

```
$pattern = '!(?<=\()[A-Za-z ,\d]*[\d]{4}(?=\))!';
```

Comment: i have added an extra condition that the year is ALWAYS present. and could u please explain ur expression. thanks :)

Comment: ah ok well that works when both the date and year is present, but not only the year :)

Comment: your code works perfect when both the date and year is present, but not only the year :)                                                   is preg_match able to meet the requirements of my condition :)

Comment: awesome....it works....one my second condition also. i understood the look behind and forward ones but could u elaborate on this '([A-Za-z ,\d]+)?[\d]{4}' please, i know \d{4} is for 4 digit numbers so u can leave it out. but the rest is a little confusing :) cheers m8

Comment: cool i understood it just one last this , in this "[A-Za-z ,\d]+" does the ',' and '\d' say 'include a comma and a digit' ? and whats the '+' sign in the end signify mate. Thanks :)

Comment: Sorry I miswrote something in my answer. The brackets `[]` contain allowed characters in this instance. So we're using the ranges for alpha characters, a literal ` ` space character and a `,` comma, followed by the `\d` shorthand character class for digits. (I used it here because you were already familiar with it.)

Comment: yep thanks ..... but what exactly does that '+' signify m8 its a little confusing lol...ive not done such an intense preg_match till now